# How do I get VBA to submit a javascript form?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am not sure if I am referencing the button correctly. I keep on getting:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
Sub russInd()
    Dim oButton As Object, HTMLdoc As Object
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, myURL As String
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set sht1 = Worksheets("Day 1")
        myURL = sht1.Cells(32, 2).Value
        ie.navigate myURL
        ie.Visible = True

        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Locate The correct forms and buttons
        Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
        Set oButton = HTMLdoc.querySelectorAll("a[href='javascript:submitForm(document.forms[0].action);']")
        'Check All Checkboxes
        HTMLdoc.getElementByID("chkAll").Click
        oButton.Click
End Sub
```

The webpage I am using is:

```
  https://indexcalculator.ftserussell.com/
```

Here is the webpage code:

[image: Web Page Code]

I need to click the next button, I did try using

`.getElementByID("CtlNavigation_lblControl")`

To click the button, however that just skipped over the command, I guess it clicked nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Use selenium , there is a library for VBA :)

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a collection. You likely want querySelector

Comment: @mplungjan That was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or simpler `HTMLdoc.getElementById("CtlNavigation_lblControl").querySelector("a").Click`

Comment: Or just call the submitform

Comment: @mplungjan For future reference do you mind telling me how I would call the submit form

Comment: Perhaps `HtmlDoc.querySelector("form").submit()`

Comment: `.getElementByID("CtlNavigation_lblControl")` is not enough - that is the span containing the link. You need `.getElementByID("CtlNavigation_lblControl").querySelector("a").Click`

Comment: And apologises for the "collection" I meant a "nodelist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You likely want `querySelector`

Try

```
HTMLdoc.getElementById("CtlNavigation_lblControl").querySelector("a").Click
```

or

```
HTMLdoc.querySelector("CtlNavigation_lblControl a").Click
```

Answer (score 1):

**Set your selector to this:** (It's saying look for any image in a parent *A* element.)

```
Set oButton = HTMLdoc.querySelectorAll("a > img")
```

**Here is the full code with the modification:**

```
Sub russInd()
    Dim oButton As Object, HTMLdoc As Object
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, myURL As String
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set sht1 = Worksheets("Day 1")
        myURL = sht1.Cells(32, 2).Value
        ie.navigate myURL
        ie.Visible = True

        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Locate The correct forms and buttons
        Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
        Set oButton = HTMLdoc.querySelectorAll("a > img")
        'Check All Checkboxes
        HTMLdoc.getElementByID("chkAll").Click
        oButton.Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following selector as it works across all steps. The number of child `a` elements within the parent with id `Ctlnavigation2_lblControl` changes so the following is a robust way to always get what you want across pages.

```
HTMLdoc.querySelector("#Ctlnavigation2_lblControl [href*=action]").Click
```

Your error, as partially correct in comments, is that you are trying to use a method of certain node types e.g. `a` tag element on a nodeList (which is what querySelectorAll returns). It does NOT return a collection. That is a very important distinction in VBA. If you try to For Each, as you would with a collection, over that nodeList Excel will crash.

Comment: The accepted answer won't work across your various steps. You want to click next each time and not go backwards in later steps.